# Recommendations on Video Editors similar to Movie Maker

Tags: video-editor, software-recommendation, windows-movie-maker

I used to create videos a lot in the past, and I am trying to get back into it. I used Windows Movie Maker back when it was 2.6 and really liked that version of it. I liked the ability to click and drag the clips into the timeline as well as when you imported the video you could click a checkbox and it would turn the video you were importing into smaller manageable clips that I could then click and drag into the timeline from the Collections section. I was hoping to find something similar to those features as well as had the ability to add in some cool effects. I was able to find something similar called Filmora. It is so close to having everything that I need. It even has a scene detection feature that is similar to the "Create video clips" feature that Windows Movie Maker has. But the clips stay in the timeline. I can't have them set aside in a collection out of the way so that I can click and drag them into the timeline in the order that I want. Does anybody know of any video editing program that is similar to Movie Maker that isn't too expensive? I don't need anything fancy. Just a few effects that I can add, a timeline editor, and the ability to create video clips when importing a video. Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried Youtube? The Creator Studio provides a lot of simple tools for free and once you upload your videos it should be possible to edit, not only easily but quickly.

Answer (score 1):

Avid just came out with a free version of Media Composer, looks very capable. "It's a fact that over 95% of all mainstream movies released in 2016 were edited on Media Composer. And so were most TV shows, too! Media Composer | First is a completely free version of the same video editing application, available on either Mac or PC. If you are an aspiring filmmaker or vlogger looking to get a start in editing, there’s no better way..."
Adobe Premiere Elements is in the price range you mention.

Answer (score 0):

www.windows-movie-maker.org/ if you like windows movie maker then you can use it here. If you want something easy to learn search Camtasia, which cost some money.

Comment: I would be very cautious before downloading the Movie Maker linked in this message. It is obviously not a microsoft website.

Comment: Good point but I'm sort of sure I got it from this site before and it was safe, but yah like you said use caution.

Comment: I actually did download it from that exact website. But unfortunately, I think because I have Windows 10, it doesn't work properly. When I was using it the sound on the music that I added to the video would go out anytime I was editing and splitting the clips. I would have to restart and play the whole video over again which is a pain because the video has to be in time with the music. I will look at Camtasia.

Comment: Camtasia is too expensive for what I am wanting, and I can't even tell if it has the ability to create video clips when importing in videos like I want. I am looking for something around $60. $200 is too expensive for my needs. Thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score -2):

> But the clips stay in the timeline. I can't have them set aside in a
>   collection out of the way so that I can click and drag them into the
>   timeline in the order that I want.

So you want "playlist" insted of timeline?

Fresh article about alternatives in 2017: http://www.techradar.com/news/the-best-free-windows-movie-maker-alternative

Free only alternatives: https://alternativeto.net/software/windows-movie-maker/alternatives/?license=free

Reddit: https://www.reddit.com/r/edtech/comments/63f9f2/alternative_to_movie_maker/ and https://www.reddit.com/r/letsplay/comments/5pcgh2/does_anyone_here_have_a_free_alternative_to_movie/

And use google!
[image]

Comment: This actually gives a great example of why this question is relevant.  The top answer on Google there is a "vendor" known for spamming SEO optimization and using basically a repackaged version of open source software that they then sell.  Similarly, my luck with alternativeto.net has been mixed at best and generally useless.

Comment: With the Google screenshot that is mostly showing poor results is removed, then this is also a link only answer.  If the links go dead, this won't be an answer.  If you can include some details from the relevant recent article in your own words, that would greatly improve this answer.

Comment: I included google screenshot to show funny fact: it can give results even in autocomplete! And I very love alternative.to, it's gives me very much cool software. To use or not to use - this is choice of peoples, because it I have different life experience, I can't give exact answer about "best alternative", everybody has own taste acctording their experience.